# Left div is static while the right div is scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate the effect seen in the about and work section on this website: http://www.melaniedaveid.com/

I want to be able to scroll down and once the div on the left is reached, only the right side is scrolling now. I'm assuming both are wrapped in a div and the right div's overflow is scrolled to, but I'm unsure how to lock the div in place until reaching the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When this question was asked, the CSS [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) was already a thing, but people probably thought it would be too much of a hassle to try and implement what you're asking using solely CSS.

I, however, have spent the last half and hour-ish building this for you out of sheer boredom. Here we go.

Now, the code itself is a bit long, so I've put it in a collapsed snippet down below. Alternatively, it's also on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkhsast3/1/), so you can save the link for later usage or something.

The structure I used is as follows:

```html
<section>

    <article>
        <!-- Left side -->
        <aside>
            <!-- left-side content goes here -->
        </aside>

        <!-- Right side -->
        <figure></figure>
        <!-- (one or more <figure> tags) -->

    </article>
    <!-- (one or more <article> tags) -->

</section>
```

With `section` as a parent, each `article` would behave as you described (fixed on the left until all images have scrolled by on the right).

Inside `article`, we have an `aside` tag which contains everything that shows up on the left side (the fixed side).

This `aside` tag contains `position: sticky` and `top: 0` to specify that until every child of the `article` is scrolled by, it should remain 0 pixels away from the top of the page.

Each `figure` tag is one image (or, if you wish, content-filled element) that should be scrolled by before the left side starts moving.

It's easier to understand when you run the snippet:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, section, article, aside {
    min-height: 100%;
}

article > aside {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}

figure {
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
figure:first-of-type {
    margin-top: -100vh;
}


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\
|* Coloring and styling so things look cute  *|
\* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
article > aside {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
}

article:nth-of-type(1) > aside {  background-color: #3c3;  }
article:nth-of-type(2) > aside {  background-color: #c33;  }

figure {
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/500x500);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
hr {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 30px;
    height: 1px;
}

.spacing {
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.spacing:first-letter {
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header class="spacing">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</header>
<section>
    <article>
        <aside>
            <h1> Section I </h1>
            <hr>
            <p> Your content goes here </p>
        </aside>
        <figure></figure>
        <figure></figure>
        <figure></figure>
    </article>
    <article>
        <aside>
            <h1> Section II </h1>
            <hr>
            <p> Your other content goes here </p>
        </aside>
        <figure></figure>
        <figure></figure>
        <figure></figure>
        <figure></figure>
        <figure></figure>
    </article>
</section>
<footer class="spacing">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
</footer>
```

---

### Upsides

1. It does exactly what you're asking;
2. It does not use any JavaScript, which should make things a bit faster;
3. I think it's great and my mom agrees.

### Downsides

1. It likely only works when `section` is intended to take up the entire page, i.e. when it occupies 100% of the height of the page. I've relied on the [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) unit (honestly because I couldn't figure out a good way to only use percentages) and that will always refer to the full page size, even if the parent element of `section` is smaller. Refer to Upside #1, though, because that's the main reason I kept it.
2. *Browser Support™*:

   - The viewport unit `vh`: [Internet Explorer 9+](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
   - The `position: sticky`: [Edge 16+, Chrome 56+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) (no support on Internet Explorer)
3. Your question has a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, implying all my effort was meaningless. Maybe some bypasser will find it useful, though.

---

I'm not really good at conclusions, but it's been fun. I hope this helps you or someone else out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the effect you're looking for is called "sticky"
Basically, you listen for the scroll event and set the css property `position: fixed` to your element A conditionally -> until the bottom position of element A is equal or greater than element B's bottom position